# Why are parenthesis in my WHERE clause messing up the JOIN? (SQL)

Tags: sql

I'm working with DVM v1.1.0: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/dvm/1.1.0?topic=reference-supported-sql-functions. When I try to use parenthesis in a WHERE statement within a UNION, and then JOIN it with another table, it gives me the following error:

> Invalid keyword LEFT found in FROM list

I have 2 tables that I need to UNION (call them U_1 and U_2), and then a 3rd table that I have to LEFT OUTER JOIN (call it J_1).

U_1 and U_2 have 2 columns that I need to filter on: 1 column that has 1 desired value, 'G' (FILTER_1VAL), and 1 column that has 2 desired values, '1' or '2' (FILTER_2VAL).

I have this SQL call to UNION U_1 and U_2 with this filter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM U_1 
WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G' AND (FILTER_2VAL = '1' OR FILTER_2VAL = '2')

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM U_2 
WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G' AND (FILTER_2VAL = '1' OR FILTER_2VAL = '2')
```

This returns (as expected) every column of U_1 and U_2 that matches these filters.

I also have some skeleton syntax for a JOIN clause on a UNION of these tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM U_1
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM U_2) full_union
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    J_1 joined ON full_union.field1 = joined.field1
```

This also works as expected; returning U_1 and U_2 together with data from J_1 where applicable.

Then, you can add some simple WHERE clauses in the nested UNION to do some data filtering:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM U_1 
     WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G' AND FILTER_2VAL = '1' OR FILTER_2VAL = '2'
     UNION
     SELECT * 
     FROM U_2 
     WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G' AND FILTER_2VAL = '1' OR FILTER_2VAL = '2') full_union
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    J_1 joined ON full_union.field1 = joined.field1
```

This runs fine and returns as expected.

However, when I add parenthesis to the WHERE clause to do more complicated filtering, and ensure that it's filtering based on the proper AND/OR logic that I want, it can't run the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM U_1
    WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G'
      AND (
           FILTER_2VAL = '1'
        OR FILTER_2VAL = '2'
      )
    
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM U_2
    WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G'
      AND (
           FILTER_2VAL = '1' 
        OR FILTER_2VAL = '2'
      )
  ) full_union
  LEFT OUTER JOIN J_1 joined ON full_union.field1 = joined.field1
```

> 13:20:33:643, 28 Jul 2021 - Error executing statement.
> 13:20:33:643, 28 Jul 2021 - [DV][JDBC Driver] Invalid keyword LEFT found in FROM list
> 13:20:33:643, 28 Jul 2021 - Stop SQL Execution (Iteration Time = 47  ms).

It really seems like the presence of () within the WHERE clause is what triggers this error to occur; why would this be? Is there any way to avoid this, or coerce the logical order of operations so I can achieve the filtering I want without using parenthesis?

EDIT 7/29:
See Power Mouse's comment below. Changing the query to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM U_1
    WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G'
      AND (
           FILTER_2VAL = '1'
        OR FILTER_2VAL = '2'
      )
      AND 1=1
    
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM U_2
    WHERE FILTER_1VAL = 'G'
      AND (
           FILTER_2VAL = '1' 
        OR FILTER_2VAL = '2'
      )
      AND 1=1
  ) full_union
  LEFT OUTER JOIN J_1 joined ON full_union.field1 = joined.field1
```

Removed the error and returned the correct result. My best guess is an issue with the SQL parser in DVM.

Comment: Try using `IN` instead:  `FILTER_1VAL = 'G' AND FILTER_2VAL IN ('1' , '2')`.

Comment: Wrap the sub-selects in their own ()

Comment: Your query is fine. Probably this is not your actual quey.

Comment: Wrapping sub-selects and using IN('1', '2') didn't work- same error.
I copy/pasted my query & changed variable names to protect info security.

Comment: add after ")" AND 1=1

Comment: Your code should work fine.  I'm guessing your actual tables are not named U_1, U_2, and J_1.  Could there be other differences that did not survive the copy-paste process?  I suspect you are missing a closing parenthesis that is not missing from your question.  Please post the actual code that is not working.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that U_1, U_2, and J_1 are not your actual table names, and that the code in your question was not copied and pasted directly to the post.  You likely have mismatched parentheses, but you may have typed the query for the post correctly.

Write your SQL in a way that is readable and easy to troubleshoot.  Then it will be easier to see that you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your second WHERE clause.  (Technically, right after the subquery.)